# Is the database already created?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm currently writing an initialization script for my sqlalchemy database.

And one thing I want to know is if the database has already been created once.
If the database is a sqlite one it's easy, I just have to check if the sqlite file exists, but what about for a postgresql/mysql database ?

So is there a generic way to find out if a database is already created with sqlalchemy ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for [sqlalchemy.schema.Metadata.create_all](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/schema.html?highlight=create_all#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all)

```
create_all(bind=None, tables=None, checkfirst=True)

Create all tables stored in this metadata.

Conditional by default, will not attempt to recreate tables already present in the 
target database.
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you :

```
CREATE DATABASE [IF NOT EXISTS] db_name
    [create_specification [, create_specification] ...]
```

from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/create-database.html